# Robotium and Jenkins UI testing errors

Tags: android, jenkins, robotium, android-testing

I first ran into this problem when trying to run Robotium UI tests on a MacOS Mini with no monitor. I added Robotium code to test UI clicks on screen, since we want to add some UI automation to our regression testing.  The error I get on the Jenkins server is  when solo.clickInList(X) is run:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: AbsListView is not found!
     [exec]     at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:492)
     [exec]     at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:406)
     [exec]     at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:388)
     [exec]     at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickInList(Solo.java:1081)
     [exec]     at com.cars.android.robotium.TestApplication.testSearch(TestApplication.java:29)
```

I found out that Jenkins needs Xvnc plugin to fake a UI so that the emulator can use it.  Make sure to check "Show emulator window" in the specific job.  Now doing that I currently get this error.

```
/Applications/RealVNC/VNC\ Server.app :$DISPLAY_NUMBER -localhost -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 24 -SecurityTypes None
```

I now get this error in Jenkins

```
Starting xvnc
[workspace] $ "/Applications/RealVNC/VNC Viewer.app" :77 -localhost -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 24 -SecurityTypes None
FATAL: Cannot run program "/Applications/RealVNC/VNC Viewer.app" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Android/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/RealVNC/VNC Viewer.app" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Android/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you show your code? You probably have to add solo.waitForView(AbsListView.class) before clicking it.

Comment: Apparently it has something to do with VNC Server on the Mac Mini that is running Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say whether the Robotium tests work on your local machine, so I don't know whether the Robotium code itself is correct.

But regarding the Xvnc setup, I see a couple of probable issues:

1. "VNC Viewer.app" sounds like a VNC *client*, rather than an X11 *server*.
2. As far as I know, you can't just run "/Applications/Foo.app" on the command line. You usually need to run the actual binary; something like "/Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo".

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and now it does try to start but I get this error. Starting xvnc
[workspace] $ "/Applications/RealVNC/VNC Server.app/Contents/MacOS/vncserver_service"
Exception: AuthorizationCopyRights: The authorization was denied since no user interaction was possible.  (errAuthorizationInteractionNotAllowed)
VNC Server has failed to launch.